# Running Grails 3.0 on Cloud Foundry

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.0, cloud-foundry

Hope you can Help me!.

I am trying to deploy a basic grails 3.0 application to Cloud Foundry but this does not work.

This application is a web services container, I executed this command:

```
./grails create-app myapiapp3--profile=web-api
```

and when running locally on my windows 7 machine it works perfectly.

I have added a **manifest.yml** file with the app settings:

```
---
applications:
- name: myapiapp3
  memory: 1024M
  host: my-api-app
  domain: cfapps.io
  buildpack: java_buildpack
```

and deploy the application to cloud foundry using this command:

```
cf push
```

But It shows me the following error:

[image]

Maybe I need to do some extra stuff here, I have not experience working with Cloud foundry and Just started to work with Grails 3.0.

Somebody can help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/example-grails.md) the Java buildpack treats Grails apps the same as Servlet apps so you will need to generate a WAR file from your app first.

This is done using:

`./grailsw war`

Comment: Wonderful Thank you very much, but just a little thing, As i am using version 3 i needed to run.     ./grails war. Thank you BeeLeeTee.

Comment: Just to expand on what was going on: if you don't specify a path for "cf push" (either with a "path:" field in manifest.yml or the "-p" cmd line parameter), then cf will push all files in the current working directory. Since you just want the compiled binaries, you need to build a .jar or .war file and specify that file as the path to push.

Answer (score 0):

additionally you could integrate the CF deployment into gradle environment by following these steps:

1. Create a gradle.properties file outside your project with your cf
   credentials

   ```
   $ cat ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
   cfUsername=john@email.com
   cfPassword=secret
   ```
2. Add the Gradle CloudFoundry plugin (/build.gradle)

   ```
   buildscript {repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'org.cloudfoundry:cf-gradle-plugin:1.1.2'
   }
   }
   apply plugin: 'cloudfoundry'
   ```
3. Configure your app services (/build.gradle)

   ```
   bootRun {
   jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
   addResources = true
   }

   assets {
   minifyJs = true
   minifyCss = true
   }

   cloudfoundry {
   target = "https://api.run.pivotal.io"
   organization = "guides-grails-org"
   application = "grailsguidepws"
   space = "development"
   }
   ```
4. Generate a war file

   `./grailsw war`
5. Deploy with gradle

   `./gradlew cfPush`

More details on deploying Grails 3.0 apps on Pivotal Web Services can be found here:http://guides.grails.org/grails-deploy-pws/guide/index.html.

Hope it helps!!